# PHP page blank in Iframe on Mobile but on PC fine

Tags: php, html, iframe, mobile

I have a Cutenews program in the iframe on the homepage where myself and others can add a blog, the page displayed in the iframe is a PHP file, when accessing from my mobile the rest of the site loads just not the php file inside the iframe, on PC its fine.

I dont know coding very well so is there a code i need to use to add so the mobile detects the page or something?

Here is my code:

```
  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Central Gaming</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"><!-- Main CSS -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" /><!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body><!-- Header -->
<div class="header-wrap d-none d-md-block">
<div class="container">
<div class="row"><!-- Left header box -->
<header class="col-6 text-left">
<h1>Latest</h1><br>
<p>

</header>
</div>


    <?php
        $number = 5;
        include("/home/centralg/public_html/cutenews/cutenews/show_news.php");
    ?>
    </h1>
    </div>
       </div>
          </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: A blank page could mean errors; are you checking out for them and where's your code? the post lacks detail/information.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/NHey3jkv

I need the stuff at the top to convert the text style and colour into the same as the websites

Comment: code must reside in the post and not as an external resource

Comment: too long by 254 characters it says.

Cheers.

Comment: `</div>
    </body>` you appear to have one extra closing div; try removing that one just before the closing body tag. Also add the closing `</html>` tag after `</body>`.

Comment: you also should not be embedding other tags inside `<p>...</p>`.

Comment: no change, i have confirmed it relates to the home.php file by trying just that page on my mobile and pc.

Nothing through the mobile other than my websites background colour

Comment: I don't know, use php's error reporting and see

Comment: I see a rampant open `<p>` with no close. I see a rampant close `</h1>` with no matching open. I see an extra close `</div>` and no end `</html>`. And when I look at `shrink-to-fit=no` ... it may be rending your page in the iframe "huge" and all you actually "see" is a small corner of color and none of the rest. And of course no idea what is in the include, or what it's doing or not doing based on any number of variables and conditions.

Comment: I have added and removed any extra / that are needed or taken away any not and still same issue. have tried zooming out and still issue.

the page is designed to show whats on the show_news.php could that be the issue?